How can i create a linear regression model not having the exact same dataset
i want to create a data regression between two financial indexes, but they don't have a perfect correspondence in the data of observation (for example one has the relevations for 17/6 18/6 19/6 but the other does not have the 18/6 and vice versa). Is there an excel formula/R package to calculate the regression both in a scenario where the data is excluded if it's not in both datasets and one where the data gets filled with the previous number if its missing? Thank you in advance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Multiple imputation" is a good search term for appropriate techniques.
